# NYC Police Codes in Blue Bloods 10-13?

Tags: realism, blue-bloods

The cast often refers to situations using Police codes, most of which I was able to dig up [here](http://copradar.com/tencodes/).

But I came across this piece of IMDb Trivia on *Blue Bloods* that states:

> In the standard 10-code, 10-13 is asking for weather and road conditions, but NYPD uses a different 10-code where 10-13 means "Assist Police Officer"

I haven't been able to find a reference to this though, the closest I came was to a link that mentioned 10-13 as a holdup.

So I guess my question is, does each state publish its separate police scanner codes handbook, or are the codes shown in such police shows purely empirical?

Comment: http://www.n2nov.net/nypdcodes.html

Comment: http://copradar.com/tencodes/

Comment: @Richard : You should put the above comments as an answer.

Comment: With no useful experience of these (other than watching the occasional cop show) I have no way of assessing their correctness. For all I know, they could be fan-fiction.

Comment: In Georgia, 10-13 is the code for an involuntary 72 hour psych hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The codes and their meanings vary from one jurisdiction to another.

An excerpt from [this](https://www.einvestigator.com/police-ten-codes/) article:

> There is no truly universal or official set of 10 codes, and the
>   meanings of a particular signals can vary between one police
>   jurisdiction and another.  While law enforcement ten codes were
>   intended to be a concise, standardized system, the proliferation of
>   different meanings has rendered it somewhat useless for situations
>   where people from different agencies and jurisdictions need to
>   communicate.

---

For example, as you mentioned in the question, the code 10-13 means

**Weather/Road report** (Most common*) - [Illinois](https://quizlet.com/85708235/illinois-state-police-10-code-list-flash-cards/), [Utah](http://wiki.radioreference.com/index.php/Utah_State_Public_Service_10-Codes), [Tampa](http://wiki.radioreference.com/index.php/Tampa_(FL)_Police_Department#10_Codes), [Florida](http://www.regoapps.com/codes/radiofl.htm)

**Request a wrecker**  - [Virginia](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2006/nov/14/usa.topstories3), [Montgomery County](http://www.regoapps.com/codes/radiomd.htm) (Maryland)

**Officer Needs Help** - [Paramus](http://www.regoapps.com/codes/radionj.htm)(New Jersey), [Ann Arbor](http://www.regoapps.com/codes/radiomi.htm) & [Washtenaw County](http://www.regoapps.com/codes/radiomi.htm) (Michigan), [Wheeling](http://www.regoapps.com/codes/radiowv.htm) (West Virginia)

**Intoxicated Driver**  - [Middletown/Cromwell](http://www.regoapps.com/codes/radioct.htm) (Connecticut)

**Suspect Escape** - [West Hartford](http://www.regoapps.com/codes/radioct.htm) (Connecticut)

**Need Help** - [Boston](http://www.regoapps.com/codes/radioma.htm) (Massachusetts)

**Fire** - [Anchorage](http://www.regoapps.com/codes/radioak.htm) (Alaska)

**Call Home** - [Hawaii](http://www.regoapps.com/codes/radiofl.htm)

**Unattended Death** - [Laconia](http://www.regoapps.com/codes/radionh.htm) (New Hampshire)

**Check for tickets** - [Columbus](http://www.regoapps.com/codes/radiooh.htm) (Ohio)

**Dead on arrival (DOA)** - [Erie](http://www.regoapps.com/codes/radiopa.htm) (Pennsylvania)

**Indecent exposure** - [North Charleston](http://www.regoapps.com/codes/radiosc.htm) (South Carolina)

**Consider suspects dangerous** - Metro Nashville & Davidson County (Tennessee)

**Drunk (Location)** - [Hampton](http://www.regoapps.com/codes/radiova.htm) (Virginia)

---

Imagine the chaos when officers from multiple jurisdictions are working together on a common emergency/situation.

To [alleviate](https://www.einvestigator.com/police-ten-codes/) that

> In 2005, the United States Federal Emergency Management Agency (FEMA)
>   began discouraging the use of ten-codes and other law enforcement
>   radio signals due to their high variability in meaning between
>   departments and agencies. In addition, the U.S. Department of Homeland
>   Security may discontinue use of the signals

---

<sub>*In fact this was meaning from the [first set of 10-codes](http://www.mcscs.jus.gov.on.ca/english/PSIS/BasicTesting/SecurityGuardStudyGuide/AppendixBAPCO/SG_appendixb_apco.html) was published by the Association of Public-Safety Communications Officials in 1940</sub>